# Swift 2 - How do I segue the UIImage to another custom class and display it?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, segue

How do I transfer a image to another view controller? For example this code takes a picture by using the camera functionality, the user confirms the image and displays it in the image view or can be selected from the gallery, how can I segue this to another custom class once the image has been chosen?

Here is the code in the ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func btnImagePicker1Clicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openCamera()

        }
        let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openGallary()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
            {
                UIAlertAction in

        }
        // Add the actions
        SKIP2.hidden = true
        BUTTON2.hidden = false
        picker?.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: alert)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openCamera1()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            openGallary1()
        }
    }
    func openGallary1()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController1(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel1(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        print("picker cancel.")

    }
}
```

Comment: if you have a gallery you could solve this with a collection view -> didSelectItem()

and when you just want to click on an image, you could lay a button without text over this image and make a segue from the button

Comment: @LucaArchidiacono Could you show me how this is written? I can't seem to figure it out cheers man.